# Add a link to a tableselect row

Tags: forms, 9

I'm interested in adding a link in a tableselect form row. Utilizing the `#options` key I can only add columns with strings. I am able to add form elements in the `#options` array similar to the `#rows` array.

```php
$rows[$nid] = [
    'edit_link' => [
        'class' => 'edit_link',
        'data' => [
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#url' => Url::fromRoute('group_manager.edit'),
            '#title' => 'test',
        ],
    ],
]

//…

$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
);
```

Implementing this example as is doesn't render this column in the table, so I assume it has failed somehow.

The 'edit_link' element works if the form is changed to a 'table' instead of 'tableselect'.

Comment: Your code is roughly correct, but there are things you didn't post so I can't say for sure why you're having a problem. Note that classes need to be passed as an array, so that should look like 'class' => ['edit_link']. Also, you only show one column - is that really all your table has? And if the 'group_manager.edit' route needs a parameter (e.g. the group id ?) that needs to be specified in your Url::fromRoute() call ... But as I said, your code is basically correct and should work for a tableselect - I use working code that's very similar to the above. Check your log for errors ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

The links column was not rendered for the tableselect form because I didn't update my `$header` array with the new element name `edit_link`.

It appears a table form does not map the element names to the header names, meaning I did not have to update the header array for my link columns to appear.  As long as the element name was in the header array Tableselect would render the column.  I believe this to be the basis of my issue.