# Get value of a checkbox that is an element in a #rows array

Tags: forms, 9

I am building a table with checkboxes without using tableselect for various reasons, but am trying to retrieve the checkbox value similar to how tableselect does.  Tableselect will populate the values array in `$form_state` at form submission. A key with the name of the form in values contains the list of selected rows. I attempted to reverse engineer how tableselect populates the values array, but I couldn't really come up with anything other than `#return_value`.  The values array using the following element is unpopulated when the form is submitted.

This is some of the form builder I'm using right now.  It exists in the `buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`.

```php
$rows[$nid] = [
    'check' => [
        'data' => [
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => 'test2',
            '#return_value' => '$nid',
        ]
    ],
],

// …

$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! As side note, `'#return_value' => '$nid'` isn't setting `#return_value` with the value of `$nid`: It's setting it to a string containing the *$*, *n*, *i*, and *d* characters.

Comment: As previous commenter said, if you are trying to return the value of the nid by it's variable, make it '#return_value' => $nid, as '$nid' will literally print '$nid' as the return value in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `'#type' => 'tableselect'` as the form field type instead of `'table'`. tableselect is a table type definition that provides a select box to the table.

From there, you can build your options for the table like so:

```
$options[
  <return_value> => [
   'field_name' => 'value',
   'field_name2' => 'value', 
  ],
];
```

Or in your case:

```
$options[
  <nodeid> => [
   'field1' => 'value', 
   'field2' => 'value',
  ],
];
```

More information on the tableselect type can be found here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Tableselect.php/class/Tableselect/8.2.x

I know you mentioned not wanting to use tableselect, but save yourself the headache and don't reinvent the wheel. That's what tableselect is for :)

The table form aAPI element is a display element used for displaying tabular data, not being used as a valid form input method.

Comment: I guess the OP asked this question because the issues described in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303018/add-a-link-to-a-tableselect-row.

Comment: Possible, but like 'table', 'link' is a display element not an input element.

Comment: *tableselect* is already a table with checkboxes. Indeed, the OP should avoid writing his own implementation of *tableselect*. I just meant that the other question should be taken in consideration, while pointing the user to avoid implementing what Drupal already offers.

Comment: _tableselect_ puts a checkbox at the start of each row and nothing else. If the person wants something else, like a checkbox in a different place or in a cell with a `rowspan` attribute, it can't be done.